# how do i make nav-item to the right without getting collapsed

Tags: html, css, menu, bootstrap-4, navbar

aight hello there, so im using bootstrap 4 and trying to create a navbar menu
here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
     <ul class="navbar-nav"><li class="nav-item">Login</li></ul>
</nav>
```

So what im trying here is I want a navbar menu and some items but I want some items not be collapsed and at the same time to be in the right.

I tried moving the item I want to be in the right moved to after toggler button and it's working exactly as I want, but in small devices and in desktop device it shows back to the left.

I tried moving the item I want to be in the right after the div collapse element but it collapses in small devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by separating the navbars into two separate divs, using bootstrap4 `row` and `col`, and giving a padding of 0 to the two separate divs. I used an in-line style to position the Login item but this is just for illustration purposes. It would be better to convert the in-line style into a class.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 p-0">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="height:4rem;">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
                 data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"           
                 aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 p-0 ">
            <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-light bg-light" style="height:4rem;">
                <ul class=" list-unstyled mr-4" style="margin-top:1rem;"> <li class=" float-right">Login</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies. The environment that I used to test your code was set up a bit differently than the one used for regular html pages. Please change the `margin-top:3.75rem;`inline style to `margin-top:1rem`. This should correct the height of the Login item. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: hello sir, thanks for helping me out, but still its kinda buggy in small devices

http://prntscr.com/objc2v

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. The height discreprancy on certain devices and screen sizes can be fixed by adding a fixed height to the two nav elements. Eg: `height:4rem;`. I edited my answer again to reflect this fix.